# iptables with NTP

Tags: iptables, ntp

I am using `iptables` to filter the traffic and also `chronyd` to synchronize the system time. However, I am not getting it to work, somehow `chronyd` cannot access the NTP server.

Here are my iptables rules:

```
# iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

And here is me trying to sync the system time:

```
# chronyd -4 -q 'server 0.openembedded.pool.ntp.org iburst'
2021-01-27T09:06:15Z chronyd version 3.5 starting (+CMDMON +NTP +REFCLOCK +RTC -PRIVDROP -SCFILTER -SIGND +ASYNCDNS -SECHASH +IPV6 -DEBUG)
2021-01-27T09:06:15Z No suitable source for synchronisation
2021-01-27T09:06:15Z chronyd exiting
```

When I clear all the rules, the above sync command works without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your computer tries to access the NTP server the source port will be indeterminate and the destination on the server will be 123. So, the opposite of what you currently have. Do this instead:

```
# iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

EDIT: From comment questions:

For the INPUT chain `--sport 123` means the port on the remote machine, and for the OUTPUT chain `--dport 123` means the port on the remote machine.

One rule can work on multiple network interfaces by not specifying a network interface, although I do not understand why you would want to do that. So (untested):

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: edited the answer to include further answers.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifications @doug-smythies

Comment: @DougSmythies I have tried that as well but it doesn't work (the chronyd command fails as before). FYI: We have two interfaces and want to sync time only over eth0 (though I tried without eth0, the same outcome).

Comment: I had also to enable port 53 for the DNS look up, then it worked.

Comment: Yes, I meant to mention that you would likely need to allow some other things for minimal operation. I assume you are using static IP addresses, otherwise you'll need to allow ports 67 and 68. Typically, one allows whatever outgoing traffic and RELATED,ESTABLISHED incoming.